# why udev rule is never triggered in real reboot, but `udevadmin test` result is still fine?

Tags: udev, battery

Here is my example rule:

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/55-battery-charge.rules 
ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="BAT*", SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{charge_control_end_threshold}="60"
```

`udevadm test /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0` works fine:

```
BAT0: /etc/udev/rules.d/55-battery-charge.rules:1 ATTR '/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:20/PNP0C09:01/PNP0C0A:03/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold' writing '60'
BAT0: /etc/udev/rules.d/55-battery-charge.rules:1 Failed to write ATTR{/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:20/PNP0C09:01/PNP0C0A:03/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold}, ignoring: Permission denied
DEVPATH=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:20/PNP0C09:01/PNP0C0A:03/power_supply/BAT0
...
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=power_supply
USEC_INITIALIZED=2126021481
...
```

During real boot, the udev debug log did not show any triggered rule for BAT0:

```
journalctl -b 0 -u systemd-udevd | grep BAT0
systemd-udevd[591]: BAT0: Device (SEQNUM=4977, ACTION=add) is queued
systemd-udevd[591]: BAT0: sd-device-monitor: Passed 734 byte to netlink monitor
systemd-udevd[668]: BAT0: Processing device (SEQNUM=4977, ACTION=add)
systemd-udevd[668]: BAT0: Device (SEQNUM=4977, ACTION=add) processed
systemd-udevd[668]: BAT0: sd-device-monitor: Passed 734 byte to netlink monitor
```

I did initramfs already and the rule did loaded at boot time:

```
systemd-udevd[591]: Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/55-battery-charge.rules
```

weird, if I remove `SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply"` it works in halfway:

```
systemd-udevd[589]: BAT0: Device (SEQNUM=4976, ACTION=add) is queued
systemd-udevd[589]: BAT0: sd-device-monitor: Passed 735 byte to netlink monitor
systemd-udevd[667]: BAT0: Processing device (SEQNUM=4976, ACTION=add)
systemd-udevd[667]: BAT0: /etc/udev/rules.d/55-battery-charge.rules:1 ATTR '/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:20/PNP0C09:01/PNP0C0A:03/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold' writing '60'
systemd-udevd[667]: BAT0: /etc/udev/rules.d/55-battery-charge.rules:1 Failed to write ATTR{/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:20/PNP0C09:01/PNP0C0A:03/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold}, ignoring: No such file or directory
systemd-udevd[667]: BAT0: Device (SEQNUM=4976, ACTION=add) processed
systemd-udevd[667]: BAT0: sd-device-monitor: Passed 735 byte to netlink monitor
```

It seems when the BAT0 added, the charge_control_end_threshold sysfs does not exist yet. How can I make sure it only happened when the threshold file is exposed already?

hmm... now I see, another kernel module actually expose the parameter much later after BAT0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During boot some device like BAT0 is added very early. Then some other kernel modules can expose additional files/attributes into BAT0's sysfs. Thus the rules set those additional attributes can fail if the rule is based on `ACTION==add`

Comment: so.. what's the solution? How to do it properly, then?

Comment: this depends on which module actually expose that attributes. You need to dig into kernel source code to figure it out. Unfortunately the entire sysfs ecosystem is still messy. There is no generic guide for this, it is always case by case. Even worse, module name/which module actual expose what can change at any time. So even you find a solution for some version, it can be very fragile @FrederickNord

Comment: since there is no clear api for these stuff. Anything related to those is better to be part of the kernel source code, otherwise it is hard to test/maintain. So the correct way to do this is to contribute to kernel modules and expose a modprobe parameter charge_control_end_threshold, then people can set it as kernel parameter at boot time.

Comment: have you tried matching on `ACTION=="!remove"`? And do you know which driver is dynamically adding sysfs attributes without throwing a uvent? That's probably considered a bug.